# Tangent of 2 times arc cosine of -3/4

Tags: trigonometry

```
Tan[ArcCos[-3/4]
```

Returns the exact answer:

-(Sqrt[7]/3)

But:

```
Tan[2 ArcCos[-3/4]]
```

Does not return an exact answer. Any way to force it to return an exact answer?

Comment: `Tan[2 ArcCos[-3/4]] // FunctionExpand` returns `-3*Sqrt[7]`

Comment: Or `Tan[2 ArcCos[-3/4]] // TrigToExp // FullSimplify`

Comment: @BobHanlon Awesome, so helpful for tomorrow's class. Thanks.